# Unit test for order in queryset in admin.py

Tags: python, django, filter, django-queryset, admin

I made solution in django 1.11, in admin - show on the top of the list in admin panel upcomming events in 2 months (60 days). Rest (also upcomming but for example for 3 months - 90 days) show below.

I would like to test my solution so I wrote unit test. But when I'm printing objects is in this order: `Event title 1, Event title 2, Event title 3` and should be: `Event title 1, Event title 3, Event title 2`.

I don't know where I made mistake.

Here is queryset in admin.py

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    next_two_months = datetime.today() + timedelta(days=60)
    not_three_months = datetime.today() + timedelta(days=90)
    qs = super(EventAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    next_two_months_events_list = qs.filter(event_from__gte=next_two_months, event_from__lte=not_three_months)
    rest_events_list = qs.filter(date__lte=datetime.today()).order_by('event_from')
    return next_two_months_events_list | rest_events_list
```

Here is my test code:

```
def test_queryset_events_list(self):
    self.client.login(**self._get_superuser_data())
    factories.EventFactory.create(title='Event title 1', date=date(2018, 7, 24),
                                  event_from=datetime(2018, 8, 22, 10, 0, 0, 0),
                                  event_to=datetime(2018, 8, 24, 10, 0, 0, 0))
    factories.EventFactory.create(title='Event title 2', date=date(2018, 7, 24),
                                  event_from=datetime(2019, 7, 24, 10, 0, 0, 0),
                                  event_to=datetime(2019, 7, 29, 10, 0, 0, 0))
    factories.EventFactory.create(title='Event title 3', date=date(2018, 7, 24),
                                  event_from=datetime(2019, 2, 22, 10, 0, 0, 0),
                                  event_to=datetime(2019, 2, 24, 10, 0, 0, 0))
    url = reverse('admin:events_event_changelist')
    response = self.client.get(url)
    print(models.Event.objects.all()[0])
    print(models.Event.objects.all()[1])
    print(models.Event.objects.all()[2])
    self.assertEquals(models.Event.objects.count(), 3)
```

Comment: In you test you retrieve `QuerySet` with out any order. You you add `.order_by('event_from')` it will be in correct order. And why you printing `models.Event.objects.all()`? It does not make any sense. I think you want to print `Event` instances from yours **`response`** object.

Comment: `obj = factories.EventFactory.create(title='Event title 1', date=date(2018, 7, 24), event_from=datetime(2018, 8, 22, 10, 0, 0, 0), event_to=datetime(2018, 8, 24, 10, 0, 0, 0))
        self.assertContains(response, obj)`

This code is not working for me